# What can I do to fix 'Unable to find definition' errors when using ALSA with Raspberry Pi and USB PnP Sound Device as microphone for Python code?

Tags: python, audio, microphone, alsa

How do I fix ALSA to see the USB mic on raspberry pi

When I run the python code
import speech_recognition as sr
from datetime import date
from time import sleep
r = sr.Recognizer()
mic = sr.Microphone()

I get the following errors

ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_hdmi.pcm.front.0:CARD=0'
Things I have checked include right clicking on the speaker Icon and the Audio inputs indicate USB PnP Sound Device, and making sure the .asound rc, asound,config and the alsmixer are all correct.
[ALSAMixer pix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G90a5.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can try setting the default audio device to your USB microphone. You can do this by editing the ALSA configuration file (/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf) and adding the following lines:

```
defaults.ctl.card 1
defaults.pcm.card 1
```

This will set the default audio device to card 1 (which should be your USB microphone). After making these changes, you should restart ALSA by running the following command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/alsa-utils restart
```

If this does not work, you can try updating your ALSA configuration by running the following command:

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.. I have tried the pcm settings using card but no joy. I will review my alsa.conf file again and let all know the outcome.

Comment: Still no joy. with the suggestions. I list the capture devices and this is what I get. Did  add the defaults.ctl.card 1
defaults.pcm.card 1 info to the .asound file still no help  My thought is that if the arecord-l result displays the following it should work**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 2: Device [USB PnP Sound Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0 I can record wave files outside of python but when alsa called within python no joy.The suggestion of adding defaults.ctl.card 1
defaults.pcm.card 1 did not work. Any help

Comment: I did not notice the error information has changed when I added  defaults.ctl.card 1
defaults.pcm.card 1

Comment: I did not notice the error message changed form  ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_hdmi.pcm.front.0:CARD=0 to  ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_headpho.pcm.front.0:CARD=1' when I added the defaults.ctl.card 1
defaults.pcm.card 1.. Still no joy calling the mic from python any additional thoughts..